# SQL separate dataset for stats - collection of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, dataset

In a query (MainQuery, not complex for the sample), I need counters on different fields, there is a way for these counters appear in a separate dataset rather than in all the lines?
Thanks for your help.

```
WITH 
MainQuery  AS(
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tb17.[NO]) AS OrderId,
* FROM [OFFRES] tb17),

Counters as (SELECT *,
(select MAX(OrderId) FROM MainQuery ) AS 'TotalRecs',
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=215 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc215,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=220 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc220,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=526 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc526,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=209 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc209,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=223 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc223 
/*...*/
from MainQuery
)

SELECT * FROM Counters  WHERE OrderId BETWEEN 1 AND 20000
```

Acutal output in one dataset :

```
OrderId No  TypeLoc TotalRecs   Loc215  Loc220  Loc526  Loc209  Loc223
1       399 218     28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
2       403 223     28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
3       404 223     28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
4       405 223     28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
5       406 223     28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
```

Outputs i would like to have :

first - all results rows:

```
OrderId No  TypeLoc 
1       399 218
2       403 223
3       404 223
4       405 223
5       406 223
```

second - all stats in a row:

```
TotalRecs   Loc215  Loc220  Loc526  Loc209  Loc223
28097       1299    1349    1324    1346    1329
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and an expected output? It is not immediately clear to me what you are asking. Thanks.

Comment: You could store your different queries in a stored proc and this would return separate datasets. Presumably you're looking to load this into a DataSet .NET object?

Comment: Yes! i want to load this in a DataSet .Net object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table structure, I would say do it in two separate select statements and select the appropriate columns only

```
WITH 
MainQuery  AS(
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tb17.[NO]) AS OrderId,
* FROM [OFFRES] tb17)

SELECT OrderId, No, TypeLoc
FROM MainQuery
WHERE OrderId BETWEEN 1 AND 20000
```

and

```
WITH 
MainQuery  AS(
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tb17.[NO]) AS OrderId,
* FROM [OFFRES] tb17),

Counters as (SELECT 
(select MAX(OrderId) FROM MainQuery ) AS 'TotalRecs',
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=215 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc215,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=220 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc220,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=526 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc526,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=209 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc209,
sum(case when [TypeLoc]=223 then 1 else 0 end) over() Loc223 
/*...*/
from MainQuery
)
SELECT TotalRecs, Loc215, Loc220, Loc526, Loc209, Loc223
FROM Counters
WHERE OrderId BETWEEN 1 AND 20000
```

Comment: no no, thank you, but my problem is to reduce the size and the returned data, and the processing time.

Comment: @achat.net You don't want to split the query, but optimize it?

Comment: why not, but without increment processing time, actual is 00:00:00.57 s, with your solution : 00:00:00.53 + 00:00:00.45 ...

Comment: @achat.net Sorry, but I don't understand your answer. Do you want to split the query? BTW, 00:00:00.53 + 00:00:00.45 isn't really a lot of time.

Comment: ben uh ... it is a full second!
We have a bit of traffic, I think my initial time is too important to be honest

Comment: Out of your idea, I actually succeeded in two separate requests.
And more easy to optimize with just minimum ... 00:00:00:04 + 00:00:00:16 !
Thanks.